# Cannot add property 0, object is not extensible when trying to push class-constructed objects indo an array list - React/NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, class, next.js

This is the code involved in that function, the goal is to create rows for rendering in a Material Ui table.

```
class User {
            constructor(id, name, email, measured, offset, paidAmount, status, home, misc, plane, transport, partner, isCoupon) {
                this.id = id
                this.name = name
                this.email = email
                this.measured = measured
                this.offset = offset
                this.paidAmount = paidAmount
                this.status = status
                this.home = home
                this.misc = misc
                this.plane = plane
                this.transport = transport
                this.partner = partner
                this.isCoupon = isCoupon
    
            }
        }
    
        const mountTableRows = () => {
            rawData.map((item, index) => {
                let user = {}
                user = new User(
                    item["ulid"],
                    item["Name"],
                    item["Email"],
                    item["Emissions"],
                    item["Quantity"],
                    item["Value"],
                    item["Status"],
                    item.Rawresult["home"],
                    item.Rawresult["misc"],
                    item.Rawresult["plane"],
                    item.Rawresult["transport"],
                    item["Partner"],
                    item["isCoupon"]
                )
                usersList.push(user)
            })
            setIsListMounted(true)
        }
    
        useEffect(() => {
            if (rawData.length > 0 && !isListMounted) {
                mountTableRows()
            }
        }, [rawData])
```

I've been getting this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot add property 0, object is
> not extensible
>
> Source pages\dashboard\dashboard.js (124:22) @ eval

```
>   122 |             item["isCoupon"]   123 |         )
> > 124 |         usersList.push(user)
>       |                  ^   125 |     })   126 |     setIsListMounted(true)   127 | }
```

Call Stack mountTableRows

> pages\dashboard\dashboard.js (107:16) eval
> pages\dashboard\dashboard.js (131:12)

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I was trying to push into an state without using the setState function

```
 usersList.push(user)
```

So i read my code again and noticed my stupidity haha
To fix the issue i just replaced the code above with this one below

```
setUsersList(current=>[...current, user])
```